# Socks5 server on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, proxy

I would like to setup socks proxy on my Debian VPS.
I try to use squid but its to hard for me.
I saw a Dante software and think about it.

I would like to setup dante to work with the web browser and plug FoxyProxy.
So on server (vps-> dante server) and on the client (Firefox + FoxyProxy-> socks5 (user + password))
It should be public access to the socks but allowed to use it with atentication.

If not Dante, what other program?

I need complete instructions on how to set up a publicly accessible server socks5 with authentication to works fine with the browser with the addition of FoxyProxy

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to use specific software to create a socks proxy. Go simple, use ssh:

On your firefox, edit the following parameters:

```
network.proxy.socks           127.0.0.1
network.proxy.socks_port      1500
network.proxy.socks_version   5
```

You can use `about:config` or the graphic interface. Its your call.

Then, log into your ssh server, using the following parameters: `ssh -D 1500 user@host.com`. Create as many users as you want on the server, so they can be "proxied" separatedly. Note that this command must ran with root user, or with a user that have privileges to bind ports on your machine.

Done. If you have other applications that don´t support socks as a native option, you can use [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) on them.

Comment: ok, great, what if i got bind something already to local? like tor for an example. 127.0.0.1:9050 can I bind ssh tunnel to other port and use proxychain?

Comment: For sure. You could use any port you want, like 6000 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Also one more tip for Firefox.

If you want your DNS queries to go through this SSH tunnel open "about:config" again and set:

```
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns = true
```